# Why does embedding records increase my collection size so much in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have two sets of data. Let's say `Dataset A` and `Dataset B`.

When I add them separately to individual collections the sizes are as follows:

`Dataset A` is 199 MB | 56214 Documents 
`Dataset B` is 70.94MB | 77049 Documents

I want this data connected but if I embed the data of `Dataset B` into the records of `Dataset A` and add this as a collection, suddenly that collection size is 5 GB+.

The records are in an array like so and they are just strings.

```
records: Array
   0:ObjectFromDatasetB
   1:ObjectFromDatasetB
   2:ObjectFromDatasetB
   3:ObjectFromDatasetB
   4:ObjectFromDatasetB
   5:ObjectFromDatasetB
```

Why is there such a massive increase in the collection size and what can I do to mitigate this?

Code I'm using for looping through both datasets and adding data to an array in Dataset A. Below "assessments" is Dataset A and "repairs" is Dataset B.

```
assessments = df1.to_dict(orient="records")
repairs = df2.to_dict(orient="records")

for item in repairs:
    for key in assessments:
        if item["_parent_index"] == key["_index"]:
            if "repairs" not in key:
                key["repairs"] = []
                key["repairs"].append(item)
            else:
                key["repairs"].append(item)
```

Comment: How are you determining the data size?  Do you have a code snippet that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "embed the data", i.e. how to you make it? It sounds like you run some recursive operation by mistake

Comment: I was thinking it was something to do with embedded docs/arrays but I suppose it could be my loop. I'm using nested loops to compare a parent and child id and insert the records into an array in dataset A. Adding some code. My logic may be wrong here.

Comment: Data size is coming from MongoDB Atlas after I upload the collections.